# javascript functions and arguments object, is there a cost involved

Tags: javascript, performance

It is common place to see code like that around the web and in frameworks:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

In doing so, you convert the arguments `Object` into a real `Array` (as much as JS has real arrays anyway) and it allows for whatever array methods you have in your Array prototypes to be applied to it, etc etc.

I remember reading somewhere that accessing the `arguments` Object directly can be significantly slower than an Array clone or than the obvious choice of named arguments. Is there any truth to that and under what circumstances / browsers does it incur a performance penalty to do so? Any articles on the subject you know of?

**update** interesting find from http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.arguments that invalidates what I read previously... Hoping the question gets some more answers from the likes of [@Ivo Wetzel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/170224/ivo-wetzel) who wrote this.

At the bottom of that section it says:

> **Performance myths and truths**
>
> The arguments object is always created
> with the only two exceptions being the
> cases where it is declared as a name
> inside of a function or one of its
> formal parameters. It does not matter
> whether it is used or not.

this goes in conflict with http://www.jspatterns.com/arguments-considered-harmful/, which states:

> However, it's not a good idea to use
> arguments for the reasons of :
>
> - performance
> - security
>
> The arguments object is not automatically created every time the function is called, the JavaScript engine will only create it on-demand, if it's used. And that creation is not free in terms of performance. The difference between using arguments vs. not using it could be anywhere between 1.5 times to 4 times slower, depending on the browser

clearly, can't both be correct, so which one is it?

ECMA die-hard Dmitrty Soshnikov said:

> Which exactly “JavaScript engine” is
> meant? Where did you get this exact
> info? Although, it can be true in some
> implementations (yep, it’s the good
> optimization as all needed info about
> the context is available on parsing
> the code, so there’s no need to create
> arguments object if it was not found
> on parsing), but as you know
> ECMA-262-3 statements, that arguments
> object **is created each time** on
> entering the execution context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here's](http://jsperf.com/arguments-performance) some q&d testing. Using predefined `arguments` seems to be the fastest, but it's not always feasible to do this. If the arity of the function is unknown beforehand (so, if a function can or must receive a variable amount of arguments), I think calling `Array.prototype.slice` once would be the most efficient way, because in that case the [performance loss](http://www.jspatterns.com/arguments-considered-harmful/) of using the `arguments` object is the most minimal.

Comment: the idea that the arguments object is created on demand seems to have found opposition. your source is Stoyan Stefanov of yahoo/yslow whom i respect a lot and yet dmitry soshnikov says otherwise... heh. prolly differs in each browser.

Comment: Yep, from ECMA262 5th edition: *when control enters an execution context for function code, an arguments object is created unless (as 
specified in 10.5) the identifier  arguments occurs as an  Identifier in the function’s  FormalParameterList or 
occurs as the Identifier of a VariableDeclaration or FunctionDeclaration contained in the function code*. So it's more of a browser thing, I would say?

Comment: Unfortunately, both of Your tests called `f1()`... Additionally, I added a third and fourth test, since You mention the `slice` method. So I wanted to introduce one more alternative to the `slice`. The results are much more interesting. The memory copy with preallocation method is much more efficient in my computer.

Answer (score 4):

No one's done testing on this in a while, and all the links are dead. Here's some fresh results:

```
  var res = []
  for(var i = 0, l = arguments.length; i < l; i++){
    res.push(arguments[i])
  }
}

function loop_variable(){
  var res = []
  var args = arguments
  for(var i = 0, l = args.length; i < l; i++){
    res.push(args[i])
  }
  return res
}

function slice(){
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
}

function spread(){
    return [...arguments];
}

function do_return(){
    return arguments;
}

function literal_spread(){
    return [arguments[0],arguments[1],arguments[2],arguments[3],arguments[4],arguments[5],arguments[6],arguments[7],arguments[8],arguments[9]];
}

function spread_args(...args){
  return args;
}
```

I tested these here: https://jsben.ch/bB11y, as `do_return(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)` and so on. Here are my results on my Ryzen 2700X, on Linux 5.13:

|  | Firefox 90.0 | Chromium 92.0 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `do_return` | 89% | **100%** |
| `loop_variable` | 74% | 77% |
| `spread` | 63% | 29% |
| `loop` | 73% | 94% |
| `literal_spread` | 86% | **100%** |
| `slice` | 68% | 81% |
| `spread_args` | **100%** | **98%** |

Comment: I added another case to your tests:
`function spread_args(...args){return args;}`
It got highest score. On M1 Macbook, Chrome 92

Answer (score 3):

The `arguments` has two problems: one is that it's not a real array. The second one is that it can only include all of the arguments, including the ones that were explicitly declared. So for example:

```
function f(x, y) {
    // arguments also include x and y
}
```

This is probably the most common problem, that you want to have **the rest** of the arguments, without the ones that you already have in `x` and `y`, so you would like to have something like that:

```
var rest = arguments.slice(2);
```

but you can't because it doesn't have the `slice` method, so you have to apply the `Array.prototype.slice` manually.

I must say that I haven't seen converting all of the arguments to a real array just for the sake of performance, only as a convenience to call Array methods. I'd have to do some profiling to know what is actually faster, and it may also depend faster for what, but my guess would be that there's not much of a difference if you don't want to call the Array methods in which case you have no choice but to convert it to a real array or apply the methods manually using call or apply.

The good news is that in new versions of ECMAScript (Harmony?) we'll be able to write just this:

```
function f(x, y, ...rest) {
   // ...
}
```

and we'll be able to forget all of those ugly workarounds.

Comment: totally understandable. i have been trying to make a bad test case where there's some difference to be felt but to no avail. http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/LRExJ/3/show/ even in ie6 both methods come to similar times (for loop for args and arguments referencing .length and arguments[ii] in purpose) - source here http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/LRExJ/3/ and basic timer class i wrote https://gist.github.com/raw/872473/6b4c133e02075a2271cb39f14027943a48c84b7f/timer.js -  through [mootools] although that's irrelevant.

Comment: This is also my experience. I haven't seen any real difference with some quick tests that I tried. The browsers may actually implement arguments just the same as normal arrays but just not giving it the Array prototype. It would make sense to not duplicate the array functionality just for one variable.

Comment: and we'll never be able to forget all of those ugly workarounds until all users (including corporative) update their browsers to modern versions

Answer (score 2):

I would argue against the accepted answer.

I edited the tests, see here: http://jsperf.com/arguments-performance/6

I added the test for `slice` method and a test for memory copy to preallocated array. The latter is multiple times more efficient in my computer.

As You can see, the first two memory copy methods in that performance test page are slow not due to loops, but due to the `push` call instead.

In conclusion, the `slice` seems almost the worst method for working with `arguments` (not counting the `push` methods since they are even not much shorter in code than the much more efficient preallocation method). 

Also it might be of interest, that `apply` function behaves quite well and does not have much performance hit by itself.

First existing test:

```
function f1(){
    for(var i = 0, l = arguments.length; i < l; i++){
        res.push(arguments[i])
    }
}
```

Added tests:

```
function f3(){
    var len = arguments.length;
    res = new Array(len);
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
         res[i] = arguments[i];
}

function f4(){
    res = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
}

function f5_helper(){
    res = arguments;
}
function f5(){
    f5_helper.apply(null, arguments);
}

function f6_helper(a, b, c, d){
    res = [a, b, c, d];
}
function f6(){
    f6_helper.apply(null, arguments);
}
```

Comment: so can we say, that if function has already arguments defined, and you `apply` it, seems to have least performance impact?

Comment: @SujitKulkarni Looks like so, at least for the code used in this test. Real life code may have different results...