# Strange code in jQuery sources: var !== var ? x : y;

Tags: javascript, jquery

Recently I found one weird line in the jQuery sources (last version 1.9.1, Sizzle package, line 129 `funescape` function):

```
funescape = function( _, escaped ) {
    var high = "0x" + escaped - 0x10000;
    // NaN means non-codepoint
    return high !== high ?            // <--- LINE 129
        escaped :
        // BMP codepoint
        high < 0 ?
            String.fromCharCode( high + 0x10000 ) :
            // Supplemental Plane codepoint (surrogate pair)
            String.fromCharCode( high >> 10 | 0xD800, high & 0x3FF | 0xDC00 );
};
```

What is the reason to make `high !== high` comparison? It looks like `return escaped` will never be executed. Or do I miss something?

**Reference:** [jQuery Sizzle](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/6f936d47773354d63a0b9e90cb0eb3fe9abf955a/src/sizzle.js#L147)

Comment: maybe a bug? which is that function expected signature? I also see an unused ``_`` argument, ...

Comment: @redShadow Well, `_` is understandable, since for some reason (possibly to preserve compatibility) the authors need to get the second argument only, besides I'd use `arguments[1]` instead.

Comment: I think it is as the comment says, `NaN !== NaN` will **always** return `true`

Comment: @VisioN: using `arguments` can have a fairly high performance cost. In a library like sizzle where every ms can count, not using `arguments` is likely the wiser choice http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325554/javascript-functions-and-arguments-object-is-there-a-cost-involved

Answer (score 59, accepted):

In fact it is written in the comment right above:

> // NaN means non-codepoint

So it is mandatory to perform this comparison first to handle the `NaN` case as in JavaScript:

`NaN === NaN` returns `false`.

As pointed out by [James Wiseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/144491/james-wiseman) it is also important to know why the developer used `high !== high` instead of `isNaN(high)` which would have been clearer.

It is certainly based on performance. This [test](http://jsperf.com/isnanfunc-vs-isnan/3) shows that `a !== a` is **twenty times faster** than `isNaN(a)`.

[zzzzBov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/497418/zzzzbov) also indicates that `isNaN()` could be overwritten, using `!==` is also more portable.

More info from [Benjamin Gruenbaum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1348195/benjamin-gruenbaum):

> It is also worth noting that NaN does not equal to anything else as
>   well, and also it is not equal to anything else in an unstrict sense

And from [Jan Dvorak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/499214/jan-dvorak):

> Also note `{valueOf:function(){return{}}}` does equal itself

Comment: It is also worth noting that NaN does not equal to anything else as well, and also it is not equal to anything else in an unstrict sense.

Comment: Also note `{valueOf:function(){return{}}}` _does_ equal itself

Comment: But why? My assumption woud dbe that `high !== high` is faster than `isNaN(high)`

Comment: @JamesWiseman > this should be benchmarked to be sure and might depend on the browser. The thing is that VisioN thought (and I did too at first) that `high !== high` would **always** be false. Which it is not so this explains the point of this specific comparison!

Comment: Several tests in the benchmark are flawed, but it clearly shows `a!==a` is _twenty times_ faster than `isNaN`

Comment: It should also be noted that `isNaN` could be overwritten, using `!==` is also more portable.

Comment: @zzzzBov : Added your input

Comment: `a!==a` is not the same as `isNaN(a)`. For example `isNaN("c")` is true, but `"c" !== "c"` is false. The reason is that `isNaN(a)` tries to convert its argument to Number and checks the result of the conversion, but `a!==a` succeeds only if its argument is NaN.

Comment: Yes but that's the whole point of this comparison here, to handle the `NaN` case and this is what is explained in the answer

Comment: @Jan Dvorak: Sorry, why are you pointing out that `{valueOf:function(){return{}}}` equals itself?

Comment: @Randomblue to indicate that the `valueOf` function is not used when comparing objects.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Hum. But anyway `({valueOf:function(){return{}}} === {valueOf:function(){return{}}})` evaluates to `false`.

Comment: @Randomblue neither does `{}==={}`

Comment: @JanDvorak: Yes, I know all of that. I'm just puzzled by your comment; I still don't understand what you were thinking. But it's no big deal. :)

Answer (score 13):

The condition `high !== high` returns true, when high is `NaN`.I wonder why the jQuery guys did not used the much clear `isNaN(high)` function instead, but that was probably due to performance reasons as koopajah pointed out.

`NaN` (`N`ot-`a`-`N`umber) means a result that cannot be represented as a `Number`. It is an undeterminated number.

---

**Why NaN === NaN returns false ?**

Consider

```
0/0          = NaN
Math.asin(2) = NaN
```

You know that `0/0` is different than `Math.asin(2)`, so why whould `NaN` be equal to `NaN`?

Comment: Another potential reason why `NaN === NaN` returns false is `NaN` has more than one bit pattern.

Answer (score 6):

I'm piggy-backing on some of the comments here, but think this worthy information.

Some comments on the original question have suggested that this method of checking for NaN is actually much faster than `isNaN()`

When taken in conjunction with the following alternative to `parseInt` `parseFloat` we have a very fast way of converting to a number and checking its numeric state.

[Is Subtracting Zero some sort of JavaScript performance trick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665984/is-minus-zero-some-sort-of-javascript-performance-trick)

So instead of

```
function Translated(val) {
    var x = parseFloat(val);
    if (!isNaN(x)) {
        alert("Not a number");
    }
}
```

We can have

```
function WTF(val) {
    var x = val - 0;
    if (x !== x) {
        alert("Not a number");
    }
}
```

Comment: `val - 0` is *not* a suitable substitute for `parseFloat(val)`. For example, the results are very different if `val = '0xFF'`.

Comment: `Number(val)` is equivalent to `val - 0`, or more simply `+val`.