# Javascript idiom: What does if (x === +x) do?

Tags: javascript, arrays, idioms, triple-equals

Reading through the source code of `underscore.js` I stumbled upon the [following line](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/0ab5bdccd41e55fb02331ec7d2d0053e0bdac9e3/underscore.js#L79):

```
... if (obj.length === +obj.length) { ...
```

That's a bit confusing for me. What is actually being compared here? I believe it has something to do about detecting native arrays, but cannot figure out what's actually going on. What does the `+` do? Why use `===` instead of `==`? And what are the performance benefits of this style?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `+` coerces the value to an Number (much like `!!` coerces it to a boolean).

```
if (x === +x)
```

...can be used to confirm that `x` itself contains an integer value.  In this case it may be to make sure that the length property of `obj` is an integer and has not been overwritten by a string value, as that can screw up iteration if `obj` is treated as an array.

Comment: There are no integers in JavaScript.

Comment: `+'5.5'` is `5.5`, you are looking for _Number_. (& @ Salman, Integers will be introduced in ES6)

Comment: To be precise `+` is a shortcut for `parseFloat` and not for `parseInt`. So it coerces the value to float (or *"Number"* type).

Answer (score 1):

It is a silly (IMO) way of checking if `obj.length` is a [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number). This is better:

```
typeof obj.length == "number"
```

Comment: Why is this silly? What is the preferred alternative?

Comment: I don't think it's silly. Maybe it is even faster than `typeof` way.

Comment: lazy? yes.. silly? nahhh... `Number(obj.length)`is so much more to type in ;)

Comment: @SalmanA Well, the same goes for [this wonderful discovery](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14772076/1249581).

Comment: I am actually surprised by the performance: http://jsperf.com/expr-expr-vs-typeof-expr

Comment: @SalmanA Yeah, and this is really weird. So the method is not that silly as it might look like.

Answer (score 1):

The + coheres what is on the right side to be a number.

In this case if length was not a property on the object undefined would be returned. `+ undefined` will yield `Nan` and this evalutation be false.

If the string can be coheres-ed into a number then it will be.. e.g  `+ '1'` will yield `1` as a `Number` this is especially important when dealing with hex values in string form e.g. `+'0x7070'` yields `28784`

Comment: Interesting. I guess the value of `+"everthing but a number"` is also `NaN`?

Comment: Updated my answer to clarify! If you need anything else let me know!