# Why is IsNaN(x) different from x == NaN where x = NaN

Tags: javascript, nan

Why are these two different?

```
var x = NaN; //e.g. Number("e");
alert(isNaN(x)); //true (good)
alert(x == NaN); //false (bad)
```

Comment: Consider `NaN === NaN // false`. Ducks aren't Bunnies `Ducks !== Bunnies`, but neither are a _Number_ so both are `NaN`, hence `NaN` can't be assumed equal to itself and therefore `==` and `===` must return `false`.

Comment: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/

Comment: Consider for a second why they would have an `isNaN` function in the first place.

Comment: Equality operator (== and ===) cannot be used to test a value against NaN. Use isNaN instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN

Comment: Think of it this way: `isNaN()` exists *because* the `==` comparisons cannot work in the "common sense" way, according to the IEEE floating-point spec.

Comment: There was a good discussion about checking for `NaN` here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14772076/1249581.

Comment: Good comments, but existence of isNaN doesn't imply that == doesn't work. Helper functions is a common place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Nothing* is equal to `NaN`. Any comparison will always be `false`.

In both the strict and abstract comparison algorithms, if the types are the same, and either operand is `NaN`, the result will be `false`.

> If Type(x) is Number, then
>
> - If `x` is `NaN`, return `false`.
> - If `y` is `NaN`, return `false`.

In the abstract algorithm, if the types are different, and a `NaN` is one of the operands, then the other operand will ultimately be coerced to a number, and will bring us back to the scenario above.

Comment: Really? Infinity looks like the same as NaN. How about Infinity == Infinity. How come it returns true?

Comment: @bighostkim: *"Infinity looks like the same as NaN..."*  I don't know what you mean by that. They're not the same.

Comment: typeof Infinity is number, as the same as typeof NaN. As you said, the other operand will ultimately be coerced to a number.

Comment: What I think is "NaN" does not have a value. so ==, which compares value, is meaningless. so is === to compare value and type.

Comment: @bighostkim: If the *types* are different, the non-numeric operand will be coerced to a number. Since the types of `Infinity` and `NaN` are the same, it the becomes a simple value comparison, except that if either operand is `NaN` *(as in this example)*, the result will always be `false`. http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3

Comment: ...both `==` and `===` take into consideration the types of the operands. It's just that the `==` will perform coercion until the types of the operands match, whereas the `===` will immediately return `false` if the types don't match.

Answer (score 1):

> The equality and inequality predicates are non-signaling so x = x returning false can be used to test if x is a quiet NaN.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)

This is the rule defined in IEEE 754 so full compliance with the specification requires this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The following operations return NaN

```
The divisions 0/0, ∞/∞, ∞/−∞, −∞/∞, and −∞/−∞
The multiplications 0×∞ and 0×−∞
The power 1^∞
The additions ∞ + (−∞), (−∞) + ∞ and equivalent subtractions.
Real operations with complex results:

The square root of a negative number
The logarithm of a negative number
The tangent of an odd multiple of 90 degrees (or π/2 radians)
The inverse sine or cosine of a number which is less than −1 or greater than +1.
```

The following operations return values for numeric operations. Hence `typeof` Nan is a number. NaN is an undefined number in mathematical terms. ∞ + (-∞) is not equal to ∞ + (-∞). But we get that NaN is `typeof` number because it results from a numeric operation.

From [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN):

Comment: Why the downvote, guys? Atleast tell me so that i can improve. :|

Comment: I didn't down vote but it seems clear to me that you have not answered the question **why**.

Comment: @ChaosPandion, Isnt it obvious? The following operations return values  for numeric operations hence typeof Nan is a number. NaN is an undefined number in mathematical terms. ∞ + (-∞) is not equal to ∞ + (-∞). But we get that NaN is typeof number because it results from a numeric operation. That's what i wrote.

Comment: It really isn't obvious. You have to consider it from the perspective of a novice.

Comment: @ChaosPandion Hmmm, I guess so. Anyway updated my answer.

Comment: You lost me at the the first infinity.