# In JavaScript, why does isNaN(value) differ to value == NaN?

Tags: javascript, nan

As it says in the question really, I tried `value == NaN` and it was false and then remembered that I should be using `isNaN(value)` to check for this.

Why the difference?

Comment: Unlike all other possible values in JavaScript, it is not possible to rely on the equality operators (`==` and `===`) to determine whether a value is `NaN` or not, because both `NaN == NaN` and `NaN === NaN` evaluate to `false`. Hence, the necessity of an `isNaN` function - see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) for more info

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14986361/why-is-isnanx-different-from-x-nan-where-x-nan

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the rationale for all comparisons returning false for IEEE754 NaN values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`both NaN == NaN and NaN === NaN evaluate to false` as from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

`NaN` is a special value which you can think of as for example `Infinity`. `Infinity` is not equal to another `Infinity` as it has **NO DEFINED VALUE**.

Comment: Awesome comparison kool, solid one

Comment: You might want to make it clear that you're referring to the mathematical concept of infinities, not the `Infinity` variable in JavaScript (as `Infinity === Infinity` in JavaScript).

Answer (score 3):

I can't put it any better than [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) do so...

> Unlike all other possible values in JavaScript, it is not possible to rely on the equality operators (`==` and `===`) to determine whether a value is `NaN` or not, because both `NaN == NaN` and `NaN === NaN` evaluate to `false`. Hence, the necessity of an `isNaN` function.