# `arguments` increases the running time (mysteriously)

Tags: javascript

I have implemented a simple lightweight `every` function. I have noticed that if the variable `arguments` is somehow used inside the function -- it **increases** the running time from **800 ms** to **1300 ms** (in my case). What causes this?

I use *Chrome 29.0.1547.66 m*.

http://jsfiddle.net/4znzy/

```
function myEvery(list, fun, withArgument) {
    var i;

    fun = fun || function(val) { return val };

    arguments; // with this statement the time is 1300 ms
               // if you comment it out -- 800 ms

    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      if (!fun.call(list, list[i], i)) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
};

// Create a huge array
var list = [];
for (i = 1; i < 20000000; i++) {
    list.push(i);
}

// Measure the time
t1 = (new Date).getTime();
myEvery(list);
t2 = (new Date).getTime();

alert(t2 - t1);
```

(If to measure the time to perform the `arguments` statement itself, it is 0 ms.)

Comment: Use of `arguments` probably gets in way of JIT compiler. What browser do you use?

Comment: see: [javascript functions and arguments object, is there a cost involved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325554/javascript-functions-and-arguments-object-is-there-a-cost-involved)

Comment: In Firefox 23.0 the difference is much more drastic ~270/~7500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appearance of `arguments` is like a dynamic getter for the function's parameters, which have to be read from the stack - and are copied. Large objects (not just big but also many) like your `list` parameter must also be **copied**.

You can see this by replacing the `arguments` line with

```
var args = [list.slice(0)]; // copy parameter
```

which results in similar times. Additional 150 with `arguments` and 200 with `slice()` on my machine.

Depending on the implementation of the JS engine this will be slower or faster, but will surely add time to the execution. There are *probably* (haven't tested it) quite big differences between different browsers or alternative JS engines.

Comment: The function is called only once, and the argument object is created once. The long loop takes place inside the function after the argument statement.